# It takes too long TeX4ht to complete

Tags: tex4ht

I want to use TeX4ht for my personal website. However, it takes too long (like 10 minutes long) for TeX4ht to complete in Windows 8.1

Is this normal? Can I do anything to make it shorter?

My `.tex` file is 8KB and I do not use any images.

Comment: How large is your document? Do you use Tikz? Do you use images for math?

Comment: so it is not normal for such small file. could you post it somewhere?

Comment: @cagirici can you post the MWE.